# Making Numbers/Gauge move more smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have made a code that gives a somewhat accurate representation of how a steam engine/boiler would work and now what I want to do is make the numbers go more smoothly. I have a function that means when I have a toggle button on it makes temperature, pressure, speed etc rise however the numbers rise quite harshly. Currently, I have the interval time between numbers rising set to every 0.5 seconds but I want to change that to every 0.1 seconds while also not having to write massive arrays filed with numbers. If you could help that would be fantastic.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Boiler Temperature Control</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: black;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 600px;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 36px;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .image-container {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      height: auto;
    }

    .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #8B4513;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      margin: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
    }

    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #CD853F;
    }

    .temperature-container, .heater-status-container, .pressure-container {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .temperature-container h2, .heater-status-container h2, .pressure-container h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .temperature-container p, .heater-status-container p, .pressure-container p {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 24px;
    }

    .heater-status-container p {
      font-size: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .gauge {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
      font-size: 50px;
      color: #004033;
    }

    .gauge__body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: 50%;
      background: #222222;
      position: relative;
      border-top-left-radius: 100% 200%;
      border-top-right-radius: 100% 200%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .gauge__fill {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      width: inherit;
      height: 100%;
      background: #950000;
      transform-origin: center top;
      transform: rotate(0.25turn);
      transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
    }

    .gauge__cover {
      width: 75%;
      height: 150%;
      background: #979797;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 25%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);

      /* Text */
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-bottom: 25%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body> 
  <p> ‎ </p>
    <div class="temperature-container">
      <h2>Current Temperature:</h2>
      <p><span id="temperature"></span> degrees Celsius</p>
    </div>
    <div class="heater-status-container">
      <h2>Heater Status:</h2>
      <p><span id="heater-status"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="pressure-container">
      <h2>Current Pressure:</h2>
      <p><span id="pressure"></span></p>
    </div>
    <p>‎</p>
    <br>
    <button class="btn" onclick="toggleHeater()">Toggle Heater</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="playSteamWhistle()">Steam Whistle</button>
    <audio id="heater-audio" src="bonfire-hq-6991.mp3"></audio>
    <br>
    <img src="https://www.canberratimes.com.au/images/transform/v1/crop/frm/32suSVsqH3pdw6NJyh92X9D/f330b4ee-4f0b-4cba-bd95-5dce19be6c00.jpg/r0_0_3000_2003_w3000_h2003_fmax.jpg" alt="Steam Train">
    <div class="gauge">
      <div class="gauge__body">
        <div class="gauge__fill"></div>
        <div class="gauge__cover"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
let temperature = 20;
let pressure = 1;
let speed = 0;

const temperatureDisplay = document.getElementById("temperature");
const pressureDisplay = document.getElementById("pressure");
const speedDisplay = document.getElementById("speed");
const gaugeElement = document.querySelector(".gauge");

function updateTemperatureDisplay() {
  temperatureDisplay.innerHTML = temperature + " &deg;C";
}

function updatePressureDisplay() {
  pressureDisplay.innerHTML = "Current Pressure: " + pressure + " Bar";
}

function updateSpeedDisplay() {
  speedDisplay.innerHTML = speed + " km/h";
}

function toggleHeater() {
  const heaterStatus = document.getElementById("heater-status");
  const heaterAudio = document.getElementById("heater-audio");

  if (heaterStatus.innerHTML === "On") {
    heaterStatus.innerHTML = "Off";
    heaterAudio.pause();
  } else {
    heaterStatus.innerHTML = "On";
    heaterAudio.play();
  }
}

function playSteamWhistle() {
  if (temperature >= 100) {
    const steamWhistle = new Audio("sfx6-whistlescreemtrain-33567.mp3");
    steamWhistle.play();
    temperature -= 2.5;
  }
}

setInterval(function () {
  const heaterStatus = document.getElementById("heater-status");

  if (heaterStatus.innerHTML === "On") {
    if (temperature < 145) {
      temperature += 0.5;
    }
  } else if (temperature > 20) {
    temperature -= 0.25;
  }

  if (temperature >= 100) {
    const pressureArray = [
      1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4,
      4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7,
      7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10,
    ];
    pressure = pressureArray[Math.floor((temperature - 100) * 2)];
    
    const speedArray = [
      0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22.5, 25, 27.5, 30, 32.5, 35, 37.5, 40, 42.5, 45, 47.5, 50, 52.5, 55, 57.5, 60, 62.5, 65, 67.5, 70, 72.5, 75, 77.5, 80, 82.5, 85, 87.5, 90,
    ];
    speed = speedArray[Math.floor((pressure - 1) * 5)];
  }

  function setGaugeValue(gauge, value) {
    if (value < 0 || value > 90) {
      return;
    }
  
    gauge.querySelector(".gauge__fill").style.transform = `rotate(${
      value / 180
    }turn)`;
    gauge.querySelector(".gauge__cover").textContent = `${value} km/h`
  };
  
  setGaugeValue(gaugeElement, speed);

  updateTemperatureDisplay();
  updatePressureDisplay();
  updateSpeedDisplay();
  setGaugeValue();
}, 500);
```

Thank you

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of expressing the mathematical equations governing temperature, pressure and speed, instead of hard-coding endless values?

Comment: It looks like the pressure goes up linearly but the speed doesn’t. What are the formulae? Alternatively you could just do an approximation - e.g. you could do a linear interpolation for the 0.1 to 0.4 second points using the array you already have. Incidentally, I cant see that this problem has anything to do with CSS.